# storing array value in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

**I want to store form array value. but it giving some errors please help**

receiving error

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'product_name' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `bill_products` (`product_name`, `bill_no`, `suppliers_master_id`, `suppliers_unic_id`, `party_id`, `supplier_name`, `GSTIN`, `bill_date`, `bill_entry_date`, `qty`, `HSN_SAC`, `sale_rate`, `MRP_rate`, `purchase_rate`, `part_no`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (?, 111w, master_5499384803, unic_5764728886, PARTY-NO922826, dvfd, fg99, 06-08-2020, 15-08-2020, 1, 1, 11, 1, 1, 1, 2020-08-15 16:24:28, 2020-08-15 16:24:28))
This is my controller

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'product_name' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `Item_list`
```

This is my controller

```
public function purchaseentryformsave(Request $request)
   {
   
       $purchasen=new Purchase;
       $purchasen->supplier_name       = $request->supplier_name;
       $purchasen->bill_no             = $request->bill_no; 
       $purchasen->suppliers_master_id = $request->suppliers_master_id; 
       $purchasen->party_id            = $request->party_id; 
       $purchasen->GSTIN               = $request->GSTIN; 
       $purchasen->bill_date           = $request->bill_date; 
       $purchasen->bill_entry_date     = $request->bill_entry_date; 
       $purchasen->total_bill_amount   = $request->total_bill_amount; 
       $purchasen->phone               = $request->phone; 
       $purchasen->pincode             = $request->pincode; 
       $purchasen->state               = $request->state; 
       $purchasen->address             = $request->address;
       $purchasen->suppliers_unic_id   = $request->suppliers_unic_id;

      if ($purchasen->save()){

        $product_name        = $purchasen->product_name;
        $bill_no             = $purchasen->bill_no;
        $suppliers_master_id = $purchasen->suppliers_master_id;
        $suppliers_unic_id   = $purchasen->suppliers_unic_id;
        $party_id            = $purchasen->party_id;
        $supplier_name       = $purchasen->supplier_name;
        $GSTIN               = $purchasen->GSTIN;
        $bill_date           = $purchasen->bill_date;
        $bill_entry_date     = $purchasen->bill_entry_date;
        
 foreach($request->qty as $k => $p){
       Billproduct::create([
           'product_name'        => $product_name,
           'bill_no'             => $bill_no,
           'suppliers_master_id' => $suppliers_master_id,
           'suppliers_unic_id'   => $suppliers_unic_id,
           'party_id'            => $party_id,
           'supplier_name'       => $supplier_name,
           'GSTIN'               => $GSTIN,
           'bill_date'           => $bill_date,
           'bill_entry_date'     => $bill_entry_date,
           'qty'                 => $request['qty'][$k],
           'HSN_SAC'             => $request['HSN_SAC'][$k],
           'sale_rate'           => $request['sale_rate'][$k],
           'MRP_rate'            => $request['MRP_rate'][$k],
           'purchase_rate'       => $request['purchase_rate'][$k],
           'part_no'             => $request['part_no'][$k],
           
       ]);
     }


 foreach($request->qty as $g => $p){
   Item_list::create([
       'supplier_name'       => $supplier_name,
       'product_name'        => $product_name,
       'qty'                 => $request['qty'][$g],
       'purchase_rate'       => $request['purchase_rate'][$g],
       'MRP_rate'            => $request['MRP_rate'][$g],
       'sale_rate'           => $request['sale_rate'][$g],
       'part_no'             => $request['part_no'][$g],
  ]);
 }
}

    return back()->with('success',' NEW PURCHASE ADDED SUCCESSFULLY .');
  
}
```

this is my view

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">PURCHASE FORM</div>

                <div class="card-body">
            
                @if (Session::has('success'))
                    <div class="alert alert-success">{!! Session::get('success') !!}</div>
                @endif
                @if (Session::has('failure'))
                    <div class="alert alert-danger">{!! Session::get('failure') !!}</div>
                @endif
                    
                           

                     
          <form method="POST"   action="{{route('purchaseentryformsave')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">

            @csrf

            <input type="text"style="background-color:yellow ;"  class="form-control "  name="suppliers_master_id"  placeholder="SUPPLIER NAME" value="{{ $Supplierdata->suppliers_master_id }}" hidden>

            <input type="text"style="background-color:yellow ;"  class="form-control "  name="suppliers_unic_id"  placeholder="SUPPLIER NAME" value="{{ $Supplierdata->suppliers_unic_id }}" hidden>

            <input type="text"style="background-color:yellow ;"  class="form-control "  name="GSTIN"  placeholder="SUPPLIER NAME" value="{{ $Supplierdata->GSTIN }}" hidden>


            <input type="text"style="background-color:yellow ;"  class="form-control "  name="phone"  placeholder="SUPPLIER NAME" value="{{ $Supplierdata->phone }}" hidden>

            <input type="text"style="background-color:yellow ;"  class="form-control "  name="pincode"  placeholder="SUPPLIER NAME" value="{{ $Supplierdata->pincode }}" hidden>

            <input type="text"style="background-color:yellow ;"  class="form-control "  name="state"  placeholder="SUPPLIER NAME" value="{{ $Supplierdata->state }}" hidden>

            <input type="text"style="background-color:yellow ;"  class="form-control "  name="address"  placeholder="SUPPLIER NAME" value="{{ $Supplierdata->address }}" hidden>


      





      
  <div class="form-row">

    <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
      <label for="validationServer01">SUPPLIER NAME</label>
      <input type="text"style="background-color:yellow ;"  class="form-control "  name="supplier_name" id="validationServer01" placeholder="SUPPLIER NAME" value="{{ $Supplierdata->supplier_name }}" required >
      
    </div>

  <div class="col-md-2 mb-3">
      <label for="validationServer01">PARTY-NO</label>
      <input type="text" style="background-color:yellow ;"  class="form-control"   name="party_id" id="validationServer01" placeholder="PARTY-NO" value="{{ $Supplierdata->party_id}}" required >
      
    </div>




 <div class="col-md-2 mb-3">
      <label for="validationServer01">BILL DATE</label>
      <input type=" " class="form-control "  name="bill_date" id="date" placeholder="BILL DATE" value="" required  >
      
    </div>

      <div class="col-md-2 mb-3">
      <label for="validationServer01">BILL ENTRY DATE</label>
      <input type="" class="form-control "  name="bill_entry_date"  placeholder="BILL DATE" value="<?php echo date('d-m-yy'); ?>" required>
      
    </div>

 

  <div class="col-md-2 mb-3">
      <label for="validationServer01">BILL NO</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control "  name="bill_no" id="validationServer01" placeholder="BILL NO" value="" required >
      
    </div>

  </div>

 

  <div class="form-row">
 
 
<style>
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: left;    
}
</style>
<style>
  table thead { display:block; }
  table tbody { height:250px; overflow-y:scroll; display:block; }
  </style>
  </div>

  
<table id="tableAppointment" style="background-color:powderblue;">
 
    <tr>
    <th style="text-align:center;" colspan="1">Description of Goods</th>
    <th style="text-align:center;" colspan="1">HSN/SAC</th>
    <th style="text-align:center;" colspan="1">MRP</th>
    <th style="text-align:center;" colspan="1">Part No</th>
    <th style="text-align:center;" colspan="1">Qty</th>
    <th style="text-align:center;" colspan="1">GST</th>
    <th style="text-align:center;" colspan="1">Rate</th>
    <th style="text-align:center;" colspan="1">Sale Rate</th>
    <th style="text-align:center;" colspan="1">Amout</th>
  </tr>
   
   <tr>
    <td ><input style="text-align:center;" type="text" class="text-danger   form-control "  name="product_name[]" id="validationServer01" placeholder="Item" value="" required  autocomplete="off" ></td>

    <td ><input  style="text-align:center;" type="text" class="text-danger input-lg form-control "  name="HSN_SAC[]" id="validationServer01" placeholder="HSN/SAC" value="" required   autocomplete="off"></td>
    
    <td > <input  style="text-align:center;" type="text" class="form-control "  name="MRP_rate[]" id="validationServer01" placeholder="MRP" value="" required pattern="[1-2-3-4-3-5-6-7-8-9-10-12]+"numbers="onlynumbers"></td>
    <td > <input  style="text-align:center;" type="text" class="text-danger  input-lg form-control "  name="part_no[]" id="validationServer01" placeholder="PART-NO" value="" required  autocomplete="off"></td>
    <td > <input  style="text-align:center;" type="text" class="text-danger  input-lg form-control quantity"  name="qty[]" id="validationServer01" placeholder="QTY" value="" required pattern="[1-2-3-4-3-5-6-7-8-9-10-12]+"numbers="onlynumbers" autocomplete="off"></td>
    <td > <input  style="text-align:center;" type="text" class="text-danger  input-lg form-control gst "  name="gst_amount[]" id="validationServer01" placeholder="GST" value="" required pattern="[1-2-3-4-3-5-6-7-8-9-10-12]+"numbers="onlynumbers" autocomplete="off"></td>
    <td > <input  style="text-align:center;" type="text" class="text-danger  input-lg form-control price"  name="purchase_rate[]" id="validationServer01" placeholder="RATE" value="" required pattern="[1-2-3-4-3-5-6-7-8-9-10-12]+"numbers="onlynumbers" autocomplete="off"></td>
    <td > <input  style="text-align:center;" type="text" class="text-danger  input-lg form-control "  name="sale_rate[]" id="validationServer01" placeholder="Sale Rate" value="" required pattern="[1-2-3-4-3-5-6-7-8-9-10-12]+"numbers="onlynumbers" autocomplete="off"></td>
    <td > <input  style="text-align:center;" type="text" class="text-danger  input-lg form-control totalamount"  name="" id="validationServer01" placeholder="AMOUNT" value="" required pattern="[1-2-3-4-3-5-6-7-8-9-10-12]+"numbers="onlynumbers" disabled></td>
  </tr>

     <tr>
    <td ><input style="text-align:center;" type="text" class="text-danger   form-control "  name="product_name[]" id="validationServer01" placeholder="Item" value="" required  autocomplete="off" ></td>
    <td ><input  style="text-align:center;" type="text" class="text-danger input-lg form-control "  name="HSN_SAC[]" id="validationServer01" placeholder="HSN/SAC" value="" required   autocomplete="off"></td>
    <td > <input  style="text-align:center;" type="text" class="form-control "  name="MRP_rate[]" id="validationServer01" placeholder="MRP" value="" required pattern="[1-2-3-4-3-5-6-7-8-9-10-12]+"numbers="onlynumbers"></td>
    <td > <input  style="text-align:center;" type="text" class="text-danger  input-lg form-control "  name="part_no[]" id="validationServer01" placeholder="PART-NO" value="" required  autocomplete="off"></td>
    <td > <input  style="text-align:center;" type="text" class="text-danger  input-lg form-control quantity"  name="qty[]" id="validationServer01" placeholder="QTY" value="" required pattern="[1-2-3-4-3-5-6-7-8-9-10-12]+"numbers="onlynumbers" autocomplete="off"></td>
    <td > <input  style="text-align:center;" type="text" class="text-danger  input-lg form-control gst "  name="gst_amount[]" id="validationServer01" placeholder="GST" value="" required pattern="[1-2-3-4-3-5-6-7-8-9-10-12]+"numbers="onlynumbers" autocomplete="off"></td>
    <td > <input  style="text-align:center;" type="text" class="text-danger  input-lg form-control price"  name="purchase_rate[]" id="validationServer01" placeholder="RATE" value="" required pattern="[1-2-3-4-3-5-6-7-8-9-10-12]+"numbers="onlynumbers" autocomplete="off"></td>
    <td > <input  style="text-align:center;" type="text" class="text-danger  input-lg form-control "  name="sale_rate[]" id="validationServer01" placeholder="Sale Rate" value="" required pattern="[1-2-3-4-3-5-6-7-8-9-10-12]+"numbers="onlynumbers" autocomplete="off"></td>
    <td > <input  style="text-align:center;" type="text" class="text-danger  input-lg form-control totalamount"  name="" id="validationServer01" placeholder="AMOUNT" value="" required pattern="[1-2-3-4-3-5-6-7-8-9-10-12]+"numbers="onlynumbers" disabled></td>
  </tr>
 
 
</table>
<br>


  <div class="row justify-content-between">
     <div class="text-danger  col-md-2 offset-md-10">
    <b>VALVE OF GOODS</b>
       
    </div>
  </div>

<div class="row justify-content-between">
   <div class="col-md-2 offset-md-10"> <input type="text" class=" text-danger  form-control total"  name="total_bill_amount" id="validationServer01" placeholder=" VALVE OF GOODS"  required >
   </div>
 
                           
</div>
  <hr>
 
  <button class="btn btn-primary float-right" type="submit">SAVE</button>
</form>

 <a style='margin-right:40px' class="btn btn-secondary float-right" href="{{ route('allpurchasesupplierlist') }}" role="button">BACK</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

this is my route

```
 Route::get('purchaseentryform{id}', 'PurchaseController@purchaseentryform')->name('purchaseentryform');
 Route::post('purchaseentryformsave', 'PurchaseController@purchaseentryformsave')->name('purchaseentryformsave');
```

my model
**Billproduct**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Billproduct extends Model
{
     
     protected $table = 'bill_products';
     protected $fillable = ['supplier_name','suppliers_master_id','suppliers_unic_id','GSTIN','party_id','bill_no','bill_entry_date','bill_date','product_name','qty','purchase_rate','MRP_rate','supplier_name','sale_rate','HSN_SAC','part_no'];
}
```

my model
**Item_list **

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Item_list extends Model
{
     protected $table = 'item_lists';
     protected $fillable = ['product_name','qty','purchase_rate','MRP_rate','sale_rate','supplier_name','part_no'];
}
```

my model
**Purchase **

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Purchase extends Model
{
     protected $table = 'purchases';
     protected $fillable = ['suppliers_master_id','suppliers_unic_id','party_id','supplier_name','GSTIN','bill_no','bill_date','bill_entry_date','total_bill_amount','phone','pincode','state','address','delete_states','part_no'];
}
```

Comment: did you try to dump $request ? because it seems your request does not have any product_name in it.

Answer (score 0):

You should add `$purchasen->product_name = $request->product_name;` before `if ($purchasen->save())`

```
$purchasen=new Purchase;
$purchasen->product_name = $request->product_name;
```

Then

```
if ($purchasen->save()){
 $product_name = $purchasen->product_name;
}
```

Comment: TypeError
Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type array, string given, called

Comment: i was uploaded full code already , did you noticed  i'dont . have product_name filed in database,  Purchase model ,im storing product_name  in Billproduct model and Item_list model .

Comment: Check `dd($request->product_name);` before `$purchasen=new Purchase;`

Comment: i am getting this array:2 [▼0 => "book" 1 => "pen"] this is my inserted  product name

Comment: remove `[]` from `<input name="product_name[]">`. It should be  `<input name="product_name">`. Then check `dd($request->input('product_name'));` in Your controller

Comment: this time i get single value  "milk"

Comment: Do you want to save this value as array in DB?

Comment: `$string[] =$request->input('product_name');`
`$json = json_encode($string); //output  ["milk"]`